# Does my Family Reunion Visa in Germany(non-EU citizen) permit me to work for a Luxembourg-based company while residing in Germany?

Tags: germany, immigration

I hold a Germany residence permit through the Family Reunion Visa, enabling me to work in any capacity. However, I'm uncertain about the possibility of engaging in full-time remote work for a Luxembourg-based company. The company permits full-time remote work from anywhere in the EU, and I'll be a permanent employee. Any insights or guidance, along with relevant links, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You are authorized to work in Germany, so if your potential employer is prepared to hire you as a resident of Germany, there is nothing to worry about as far as immigration law or employment authorization law is concerned.